# Inject IOptionsSnapshot in Block constructor

Tags: piranha-cms

I created a new custom Block and wanted to inject an IOptionsSnapshot to read my appsettings.json values. The problem is that I get an error saying there is no parameterless constructor for my custom block.

Is there a way to somehow do this injection or is this a limitation in Piranha and custom blocks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment neither `Fields` nor `Blocks` supports parameter injection into the constructor, however `Fields` have two initialization methods that both support parameter injection, `Init()` and `InitManager()`. Given how models are constructed the easiest solution would probably be to add the corresponding init methods to `Blocks` as well.

Feel free to open an issue/feature request at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/piranha.core) and we can take the discussion from there!